# Can a Rogue's Hunter's Surprise be part of a Full Attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, rogue

If a party with the **Swing About** teamwork feat moves a rogue adjacent to an enemy, can the rogue use the **Hunter's Surprise** talent to designate prey (normally a Standard action) on his turn as part of a Full Attack action?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. You've asked a question that may have no clear answer, and I hope that's not too disappointing. Thank you for participating, though, and I hope the answers you receive are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

### Talk to the GM about the action needed to designate prey

The rogue [advanced talent](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents) [hunter's surprise](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo---rogue-advanced-talents/hunter-s-surprise-ex) as its Benefit says

> Once per day, a rogue with this talent can designate a single enemy she is adjacent to as her prey. Until the end of her next turn, she can add her sneak attack damage to all attacks made against her prey, even if she is not flanking it or it is not flat-footed.

Unfortunately, no action is listed for designating prey. Because it's an extraordinary ability, according to [Actions in Combat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#Table-Actions-in-Combat) designating prey takes a standard action to employ, but there is [some](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2pprf?Hunters-Surprise-Action-required#1) [debate](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2qn1z?Questions-on-Rogue-Talents). So far, the only answer seems to be to ask the GM.

However, the second part is clearer. The [teamwork feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/teamwork-feats) [Swing About](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/swing-about-teamwork) as its Benefit says

> If you have a free hand, as a move action you can grab a willing adjacent ally who also has this feat and place her in any other space adjacent to you. This movement does not provoke attacks of opportunity. You can do this only with allies who are able to move freely (not grappled, held, prone, slowed, or otherwise suffering restricted movement) and who are of your size or smaller.

Note that, because of the way teamwork feats work, in addition to the party member *doing* the swinging, the rogue *himself* needs the teamwork feats Swing About *and* the feat [Escape Route](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/escape-route-combat-teamwork), the feat Swing About's prerequisite, but, if the rogue has all that, once per day (as per hunter's surprise) this could be done.

That's an awful lot of resources to devote to that one thing, though. And if you're going that far, be sure to get a weapon with the magic weapon special ability [*sneaky*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/sneaky). (About which there's *also* some [debate](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2rrqz?Do-Multiple-Sneaky-Weapons-Allow-Extra-Uses#5).)